# AngularJS drag and drop Checking whether the item raised has a class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question, I have created ng-repeat which i print out li with the names.

**then after catching the li element The dndDragging class is added**(to li).

And now I have a question how to check if this class has been added, after after pick up item?

Could someone tell me how to do it?

```
<ul dnd-horizontal-list="true" 
    dnd-list="board.lists" 
    dnd-allowed-types="['item']" >

      <li ng-repeat="item in board.lists" 
          dnd-draggable="item" 
          dnd-type="'item'" 
          dnd-effect-allowed="move"
          dnd-selected="models.selected = item" 
          ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}" 
          dnd-moved="removeList($index)" >
              {{item.list}}

       </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what are you trying to do but I wouldn't go for any class checking and DOM manipulation - that's jQuery way.

What you most likely need is to put your logic in `dnd-moved` - here you would splice your array and move item out of array and put it somewhere else - there in that function (`removeList`) you can make all necessary logic.

If that's not enough you can use this to check when element started dragging:

```
dnd-dragstart
```

or this to check when drag ended:

```
dnd-dragend
```

you even have this to check if element is dragged over another element:

```
dnd-dragover
```

and just add callback functions where you can place your logic, so there's litteraly no need for class checking. I'm not 100% sure what are you trying to do but first consider reading all documentation before you start implementing solutions: https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Comment: Hey, It is so, if you catch the element and lightly move it, this element can disappear, this is because of this, that first is executed: ul[dnd-list].dndDraggingSource { display: none; }. a class dnddragging cant be add himself so fast. And the problem is that either blinks my list, or I can slightly move the item and flick it out so that it will disappear items So I want to do that so if there is a class dnddragging then do document.querySelector ("ul [dnd-list]> .dndDraggingSource"). style.display = "none" i record problem: https://youtu.be/0wRbPusGkkA

Comment: and i cant use dnd-dragover Because then I do not have other functions of this directive and I do not move the elements

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/BF8sIp0s7wk1sCzTZNjI?p=preview here in an example, i cant use dnddragover and dnd drop because in my main program stop work drag and drop because I have did it on dnd-move and $scope.$watch, in this example u can see that after Move the list name slightly will disappear

Comment: I can't see any issues with your plnkr

Comment: If u move a few millimeters gently name lists for example list 1 she can disappear, if you move faster she flashes